# I am migrating from ADAL to MSAL and getting invalid scope error

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-ad-msal, adal

In my code, I am switching from using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory to using Microsoft.Identity.Client .

Previous Implementation:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(Authority));
var credential = new ClientCredential(IssuingResource, Secret);
private static AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(appSettings.URI, credential);
return authResult.AccessToken;
```

Current implementation:

```
string[] scopes = { appSettings.URI + "/.default" };
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(IssuingResource).WithClientSecret(Secret).WithAuthority(Authority).Build();
private static AuthenticationResult authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
return authResult.AccessToken;
```

The current implementation is throwing an exception :
*AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.*

Am I missing something here?
Can anyone plz guide me?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi @A.S. it there any update? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [client credentials flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), the scope is always of the shape `"resource/.default"` because the application permissions need to be set statically (in the portal or by PowerShell), and then granted by a tenant administrator.

For example:

> Microsoft Graph: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
>
> Microsoft 365 Mail API: https://outlook.office.com/.default
>
> Azure Key Vault: https://vault.azure.net/.default

Here is the code for getting an Access Token using the Confidential Client Application:

```
public string GetAccessToken()
{

       var tenantId = "";
       var clientId = "";    
       var authorityUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";    
       var redirectUri = "http://localhost:4030";   
       var scopes = new List<string> { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };    
       var clientSecret = "";
         
       var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder    
              .Create(clientId)    
              .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
              .WithAuthority(new Uri(authorityUri))
              .Build();

       var accessTokenRequest = confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes);

       var accessToken = accessTokenRequest.ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken; 

       return accessToken;    
}
```